# What is the instantaneous rate of change given these business numbers?

Tags: calculus

-A man has 61 clients 
-Clients are growing at a rate of 1.8 per year.
-His profits are $\$ $631.42 per client per year. 
-His profits are dropping by $\$ $12.41 per client per year.

I need to find the instantaneous rate of change for his profits this year. For an equation to find his yearly profit I got (631.42(61+1.8x))-(12.41(61(1.8x)))  I don't know if this is correct but when I factored it and got its derivative I just got -226.062 and I don't feel that's right.   I know you have to find the equation to represent his profits, find the derivative, and then plug in 0 for the year to get the rate of change now but I'm not sure what to do with all the numbers and such.

Answer (score 1):

So:
$$\#\text{clients}(t)=61\cdot1.8^t$$
$$\text{profit_per_client}(t)=631.41-12.41t$$
Therefore:
$$\text{profit}(t)=\#\text{clients}(t)\cdot\text{profit_per_client}(t)=1.8^t(38516.0099-757.01t)$$
Hence, using the product rule:
$$\text{profit}(t)'=-757.01\cdot1.8^t+\ln(1.8)1.8^t(38516.0099-757.01t)$$
Where $\ln(1.8)$ is the natural logarithm of $1.8$.

Comment: Why "-His profits are 631.42 per client per year. -His profits are dropping by 12.41 per client per year." traduces to
$\text{profit_per_client}(t)=631.41-12.41t$
If both quantities say "per client per year"

Comment: I think clients are growing linearly with the year.